# How to replace special chars in XML node with SimpleXMLElement PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML file that looks something like this:

```xml
<booking-info-list>
    <booking-info>
        <index>1</index>
        <pricing-info-index>1</pricing-info-index>
        <booking-type>W</booking-class>
        <cabin-type>E</cabin-type>
        <ticket-type>E</ticket-type>
        <booking-status>P</booking-status>      
    </booking-info>
    <booking-info>
        <index>2</index>
        <pricing-info-index>1</pricing-info-index>
        <booking-type>W</booking-class>
        <cabin-type>E</cabin-type>
        <ticket-type>E</ticket-type>
        <booking-status>P</booking-status>      
    </booking-info>
    <booking-info>
        <index>3</index>
        <pricing-info-index>1</pricing-info-index>
        <booking-type>W</booking-class>
        <cabin-type>E</cabin-type>
        <ticket-type>E</ticket-type>
        <booking-status>P</booking-status>      
    </booking-info>
</booking-info-list>
```

Is there a simple way to replace/remove the `-` (hyphen) in all tags?

Comment: I think, that the simplest way is to use  regex. Else you need to rebuild the xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hyphen is not a special character in XML node names. It is a problem in SimpleXML only because it is an operator in PHP. Here is no need to change them and possibly destroy the XML.

You can use the variable variable syntax to access the elements.

```
$element = simplexml_load_string($xml);
foreach($element->{'booking-info'} as $element) {
  var_dump($element);
}
```

It is not an issue if you're using Xpath:

```
$element = simplexml_load_string($xml);
foreach ($element->xpath('//booking-info') as $element) {
  var_dump($element);
}
```

The Xpath expression is a string for PHP.

Or DOM:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
foreach ($document->getElementsByTagName('booking-info') as $node) {
  var_dump($node);
}
```

The name is a string for PHP.

Or DOM with XPath:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//booking-info') as $node) {
  var_dump($node);
}
```

HINT: You have an error in the XML - `<booking-type>...</booking-class>` has different names for the opening and closing tag.